# PHP - Save JPEG from Field Data

Tags: php, image, jpeg

I have a form which contains a field `<input type="text" name="imageData">` with the `JPEG image` data:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAEsKADAAQAAAABAAADhAAAAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs+EJ+/8AAEQgDhASwAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEA....
```

How can I use `PHP` to create a `JPG image` using this data after I post the form information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got the content of `imageData` to PHP you can split the string (using the `base64,`, then decode the actual base64 string (using [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)), now you have the actual jpeg data, the only thing you need now is to save this data (you can do this using [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
$data = $_POST['imageData'];
$exploded = explode('base64,', $data);
if ($exploded) {
    $base64_string = $exploded[1];
    $image_binary_data = base64_decode($base64_string);
    file_put_contents('new_image.jpg', $image_binary_data);
}
```